# How to add IE Compatibility View item via Group Policy?

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

I am looking to add a single item to IE Compatibility View across devices on the network. I know it's possible to deploy Compatibility View via Group Policy, but it looks like it would override the entire item list.

How can I add a single item (web address) via Group Policy instead of overriding the entire list? Ultimately it needs to check if say bob.com is already in the list, and if not then add it. But it cannot override (and lose) existing items in the list as they're needed (different departments have added different sites to their list as needed, for example some NY state websites and others EMR sites).

Devices: Windows 7, IE11

DC: Windows Server 2012 R2

Would Enterprise Mode Site List override/conflict with items in Compatibility Mode?

Comment: Is this for Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: @GregAskew Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Enterprise Mode Site List.  The site list you create can be hosted on a web site, local hard drive, or a network share.

You can use the graphical tool to create/maintain the list, but you don't have to.

Download:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42501

Use the Enterprise Mode Site List Manager tool
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640701.aspx

You have much finer granularity of control using the EM site list.  Below are some examples:

```
<rules version="3">
  <emie>
    <domain exclude="false">SomeDomainForIE8EnterpriseMode.com</domain>
  </emie>
  <docMode>
    <domain docMode="edge">edgemodesample.contoso.com</domain>
    <domain docMode="10">ie10modesample.contoso.com</domain>
    <domain docMode="9">ie9modesample.contoso.com</domain>
    <domain docMode="8">ie8modesample.contoso.com</domain>
    <domain docMode="7">ie7modesample.contoso.com</domain>
    <domain docMode="5">ie5modesample.contoso.com</domain>
  </docMode>
</rules>
```

Comment: This is awesome, but does it still allow the end user to make additions, or does it leave them with a greyed-out compatibility view dialog box in IE?

Comment: It doesn't change the Compatibility View menu selections.

Comment: You're my new hero. Trying this tomorrow.

Comment: So this list would not conflict/override Compatibility View items?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do this using native Group Policy functionality. I have the same issue in my environment, and am forced to add sites to the GPO every time I need to make an exception on any computer. In my case, we have enough sites in the list that the gains outweighs the costs.

As a hackish workaround, you could determine which registry keys contain the user's personal list and deploy them through Group Policy Preferences instead of enforcing the Compatibility View policy. That would have the same effect as if each user had entered the sites themselves without all the manual effort, while still allowing for manual additions.

EDIT: For IE 11 on Windows 8.1, The user list is stored in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\ClearableListData\UserFilter` which is a single REG_BINARY key that contains the entire list. You could deploy this key with a *"apply once and don't reapply"* option. The only downside is you would wipe out  a user's list if you ever needed to make changes.

Comment: I have a Powershell script ready for this, but I have been unable to read the key because it's in binary.

Comment: `The only downside is you would wipe out a user's list if you ever needed to make changes.` Right, this is what I need to avoid.

Comment: I believe you can read a binary registry key from PowerShell. You wouldn't have to parse it, just prep the key via IE GUI, export it to a variable, and overwrite the target key with the contents.

Comment: I would need to check if the web address exists first right? So it doesn't duplicate it?

Comment: Yes. Essentially you'd have to write a parser. Parse the key to a list of URLs, add any that were missing, reformat it to binary, then write it back.

Comment: From what I've read, it's complex enough that no one has fully figured out yet. "While this seems to work, there are several values I was not able to decode."  http://jeffgraves.me/2014/02/19/modifying-ie-compatibility-view-settings-with-powershell/